# Improving legibility on conditional statement

Tags: java, android, readability, code-readability

I am building a HTTP server for my android device.

I am using a lot of IF-ELSE statements to handle differnt requests.

As I will be sharing my code with other people for later use, I will have to make it as legible as possible. Right now, I can't even read my code with ease.

I think the problem comes from using a lot of IF-ELSE statements in one class.
For example.

```
if(purpose.equals("readProfile"){
     .....
}
else if(purpose.equals("writeProfile"){
     .....
}
    ....
```

I tried classifying them in category and ordered the conditions according to their category. But not a lot of legebility was improved. 
Then I tried writing short comments infront of each conditions. But this made even more mess.

What can be done to increase legibility for conditional statements?

Comment: Define a similar behavior for a group of requests and create specific interfaces that will hold common methods for these and class implementations to hold the specific business logic for these requests. You can create a factory that will receive, for example, the purpose (`"readProfile"`, `"writeProfile"`) and will return you the interface so you don't need to bother with these `if-else` statements.

Comment: You can learn more in the net by visiting sites like http://www.antiifcampaign.com/

Comment: In addition to what @LuiggiMendoza said, the purpose can be defined in [Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). It improves readability and can be used everywhere, instead of hardcoded strings in all places!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Luiggi Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza) stated, this is a follow up of [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18757692/1065197)...

If you are using **Java 7**, you can use a [switch-case statement for strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

```
    //month is a String
    switch (month.toLowerCase()) {
        case "january":
            monthNumber = 1;
            break;
          //partsleft out for sake of brevity ..
        default: 
            monthNumber = 0;
            break;
    }
```

(excerpt from the Oracle Java Tutorials, referenced above.)

#### Refactoring

However, this huge if-else is just part of the problem. As this seems to be a structure growing over time, I'd recommend a thorough refactoring, and using what seems to me is a [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). You should:

Formulate an interface which covers the boundaries for all the use cases:

```
interface MyStrategy {
  void execute(MyInputContext input, MyOutputContext output);
}
```

(using a void method with MyInputContext and MyOutputContext are just one approach, this is just an example, but to handle requests that have responses, this makes sense, just like how Servlets work)

Refactor the content of the big IF-ELSE statement into instances of this interface (these will be the strategies):

```
//VERY simplified...
class ReadProfileStrategy implements MyStrategy {
  void execute(MyInputContext input, MyOutputContext output) {
    //do the stuff that was in the if-else block in the "readProfile" part
  }
}

//... at the branching part:
MyInputContext input; //build this here
MyOutputContext output; //build this here

switch (purpose) {
    case "readProfile":
         // no need to always instantiate this, it should be stateless...
         new ReadProfileStrategy().execute();
         break;
    //... left out for sake of brevity
}
```

#### Refactoring step 2

If this is done, you can add the string IDs to the interface, and the instances themselves, and get rid of the if-else or switch statement altogether, you could create a Map populated even through an IOC container (like), to be up to date, and completely flexible.

```
class ReadProfileStrategy implements MyStrategy {
  String getID() {
      return "readProfile";
  }

  void execute(MyInputContext input, MyOutputContext output) {
    //do the stuff that was in the if-else block in the "readProfile" part
  }
}
```

In the class when requests are processed

```
private final Map<String, MyStrategy> strategyMap; //fill the map using your favorite approach, like using Spring application context, using the getCode() to provide the key of the map
```

In the processing logic:

```
MyStrategy strategy = strategyMap.get(purpose);
if(strategy!=null) {
    strategy.execute();
}
else {
    //handle error here
}
```

Comment: It would be great to point out that this question is a follow up from OP's latest question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18757692/1065197

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I even saw that question yesterday, and I already forgot about that...

Answer (score 2):

This may be out of scope, but just an observation

try using

`if("readProfile".equals(purpose){}` instead of

`if(purpose.equals("readProfile"){}`.

It will help to avoid null pinter exception

Comment: Most of the time I do the same, but there are cases when this solution interferes with the "fail-fast" concept - not detecting a null can be bad in some use cases.

Answer (score 2):

Enums can help - you can also add functionality to them.

```
public void test(String purpose) {
  if (purpose.equals("readProfile")) {
    // Read.
  } else if (purpose.equals("writeProfile")) {
    // Write.
  }
}

enum Purpose {
  readProfile {
    @Override
    void doIt() {
      // Read.
    }
  },
  writeProfile {
    @Override
    void doIt() {
      // Write.
    }
  };

  abstract void doIt();

}
public void test2(String purpose) {
  Purpose.valueOf(purpose).doIt();
}
```

Comment: +1 I thought of this too, but I'm afraid as this seems to be a request-response handling stuff, with a lot of cases, I would probably think twice: the code would still be at one place, being way too much. If each part is small enough (clean code-ish, let's say max 5 lines in the body of the method), it helps. But above that, it just makes things ugly - but this is just an opinion, as I just happen to have done this in the last few days, where it got a bit out of hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using some kind of Action-Interface with implementations for each block and preload a map with concrete Implementations of this action.

```
interface Action {
    void execute();
}

Map<String, Action> actions = new HashMap<>();
actions.put("readProfile", new Action() { ... });
actions.put("writeProfile", new Action() { ... });

actionMap.get(purpose).execute();
```

That will lower your cyclomatic complexity as well. Of course you should preload the map only once.

Answer (score 1):

Well, If it makes sense to separate code inside if-else condition to another class, perhaps use Factory pattern. Also make all separated classes implement common interface (eg: `MyActivity.class`) with a method such as `execute()`.

Factory decides what object (`ReadProfile.class`, `WriteProfile.class` etc.) has to be created based on the string you pass and then call `execute()` method.

```
MyActivity obj = MyFactory.createMyActivity(String)
obj.execute(...);
```