# How to implement state in command pattern

Tags: java, servlets

I am porting my Java servlet front controller from a large if-else if block to the command pattern and have created a command interface with an execute method. Currently, I am instantiating an instance of each command in the `init()` method of my servlet and storing them in a `HashMap`. I am wondering how I can run the necessary `command.execute()` within the context of a given request?

Do I add a `setContext(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response);` method to the interface and call `command.setContext(request, response)` from my `doGet()/doPost()` methods before I execute or should I not be instantiating the commands in `init()` to begin with? instead, having a constructor that takes `request` and `response` as args?

Obviously, the aim of the command is to set various attributes for a given user/session and determine the correct JSP to forward to, which it can't really do without the context.

Comment: You are probably bound for trouble... A single command is at the same time used by multiple requests... That will only work if there is no state to rely on but judging by the fact that you need the `request` and `response` it does something with it.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ah yes, I hadn't thought of that. I guess I could store factories in the `HashMap` instead and get a new instance for each request. How is the command pattern applied normally in servlets.

Comment: As I stated in [one of my  previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759042/improving-legibility-on-conditional-statement/18759152#18759152), you'd need an `execute(InputContext, OutputContext)` style for this purpose. **Don't do the factory stuff.** You should only have to use the `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` instances in your Command instances. I don't see any other object you'd need _that is specific to the request itself_, and can not be part of initialization of the Command instances themselves.

Comment: Does neither of the roughly five million Java web frameworks already do this? (And get rid of the ridiculous thing that is JSP, the template engine which has failed to grow error messages with accurate line numbers in the past two decades, as a bonus.)

Comment: @ppeterka66 Just because you do *need* to isolate state besides the request and response doesn't mean it's a good idea to share all other state. Shared state is bad unless proven otherwise, the logic should go the other way around. (And you can always add it with `static`.)

Comment: @AshleyTalbert For reference - pretty much every Java web framework that is *not* raw servlets (that I've worked with) creates command objects per-request. I'd say there is overwhelming consensus that having servlets be singletons was a bad idea.

Comment: @millimoose But what if I create Commands on the fly, with the same business logic, but for example different templates (template as in Velocity terms), maybe coming from a Spring container? I might be short sighted, and would like to learn how you would solve that issue without a non-static field.

Comment: @ppeterka66 I'm not really sure what you're getting at. The business logic would be the code of the commands, that's shared between all instances anyway. Templates can be passed as parameters or injected into the command instance. You'll have to give me a better example of when you'd **need** singleton commands. (Essentially, when creating commands per-request, you have the option of injecting all of their dependencies. An advantage of this is that you can add more of those in later versions of your framework without having to change the signature of the `execute()` method.)

Comment: @millimoose Do they create them using a hash of factories or reflection or what is the mechanism for instantiating the particular type of command per request?

Comment: `FooCommand.class.newInstance()` works for starters. Since the frameworks are configured using command class names or annotations, I'd bet on reflection and maybe classpath scanning.

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
command.execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response);
```

All state can (and should) be recorded in the request. This is easy to do by storing attributes.

Sometimes you may need to use:

```
command.execute(this, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response);
```

but probably only if your commands are `enum` rather than real objects.